# Variable being removed as a file created within a bash file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a deployment script which creates a file, it's a bit like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
...
cat << EOF > nginx/test.conf
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  domain.com;
    return       301 http://www.domain.com$request_uri;
}
EOF
...
```

However when the file is created after the deployment script has run, it outputs this:

**nginx/test.conf**

```
...
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  domain.com;
    return       301 http://www.domain.com;
}
...
```

How do I stop it from removing the variable as a result of being created from a deployment script?

Comment: Do you want the variable expanded, or left as-is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you are asking how to get the return in the output file to contain `$request_uri`  Right now when you use `cat` the shell is trying to expand `$request_uri` to the value it has, which is probably empty, so it seems to disappear.  If you want the result to contain that string, you need to escape the `$` so it won't try to expand it

```
cat << EOF > nginx/test.conf
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  domain.com;
    return       301 http://www.domain.com\$request_uri;
} 
EOF
```